# Local variable scope and for loop

Tags: java

I just have started to learn Java. I have some dummy question. I don't really get why in this situation:

```
int j = 5;
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   // do sth
}
```

my compiler says : `the variable j is already defined in the scope`. 
Why this second `j` is a problem ? I thought that it should simply shadow the first one.

Comment: Can you paste the whole exception?

Comment: "I thought that it should simply shadow the first one." I doesn't. There is no variable shadowing in Java.

Comment: you need not to declare j inside for(...) loop

Comment: problem is when you have defined two same variables in same scope, compiler won't know which one is valid

Comment: How do you want the compiler to know which `j` are you referring to inside the loop?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're declaring the variable `j` twice: One out of the `for` loop and one inside. Just delete the line above the `for` and you'll be good to go.

Local variables aren't shadowed - perhaps you had fields in mind (but that's something different from what you have here).

Answer (score 4):

A simpler yet similar scenario is:

```
int i = 0;
{
   int i = 2;
}
```

So you have two `i` variables. Which one do you mean when you reference `i` ?

The Java compiler doesn't allow 'shadowing' here. The definitions are ambiguous, and the compiler is working to warn you of this.

Answer (score 3):

For the rules for shadowing and obscuring, have a look at the [Java Language Specification, Section 6.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4)

They even provide the same example:

> Because a declaration of an identifier as a local variable of a method, constructor, or initializer block must not appear within the scope of a parameter or local variable of the same name, a compile-time error occurs for the following program:

```
class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

> This restriction helps to detect some otherwise very obscure bugs. A similar restriction on shadowing of members by local variables was judged impractical, because the addition of a member in a superclass could cause subclasses to have to rename local variables. Related considerations make restrictions on shadowing of local variables by members of nested classes, or on shadowing of local variables by local variables declared within nested classes unattractive as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take it this way. If you were allowed to declare the variable `i` in the for loop, then how would you refer to the *local variable* `i`, declared before the `for` loop? You can't do that with any qualified name, and the simple name would refer to the for loop variable. That is why it isn't allowed.

The behaviour is as listed in JLS. From [JLS - Section 6.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4):

> A local variable (§14.4), formal parameter (§8.4.1), exception parameter (§14.20), and local class (§14.3) **can only be referred to using a simple name** (§6.2), not a qualified name (§6.6).
>
> Some declarations are not permitted within the scope of a local variable, formal parameter, exception parameter, or local class declaration because **it would be impossible to distinguish between the declared entities using only simple names**.

And from [JLS - Section 6.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) **is the rest of the block** in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

Emphasis mine.

Again, in JLS Section 6.4, it is specified that re-declaration of local variable in the same scope will result in compile-time error:

> It is a compile-time error if the name of a local variable v is redeclared as a local variable of the directly enclosing method, constructor, or initializer block within the scope of v; or as an exception parameter of a catch clause in a try statement of the directly enclosing method, constructor or initializer block within the scope of v; or as a resource in a try-with-resources statement of the directly enclosing method, constructor or initializer block within the scope of v.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cause this is a duplicate local variable problem, You already define "j" variable before. Try this:

                int i = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
           // do sth
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shadowing only occurs if one of the variables is a method field and the other one is local variable. In your case both are local variables so they cannot shadow each other.

You cannot have two local variables with the same name if they share a scope in the same way you cannot have two fields with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int j = 5; // this j is visible to whole method 
 for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
      // so still j is visible to this for loop and you can use it 
      // but you can't initialize it again
 // do sth
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `j` variable twice . Rewrite your code as below :

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   // do sth
}
```

or

```
int j;
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   // do sth
}
```